# *** stack smashing detected ***: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group terminated

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When add a collision object to move_group, and set a goal to plan. This error happened, what's the meaning?
this error followed

```
[move_group-3] process has died [pid 3617, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --debug __name:=move_group __log:=/home/jwx/.ros/log/07137956-8d97-11ea-b28a-c8d3ff1c1134/move_group-3.log].
log file: /home/jwx/.ros/log/07137956-8d97-11ea-b28a-c8d3ff1c1134/move_group-3*.log
```

This must be something wrong with my moveit collision avoid planning , Because when I run the official tutorial ,the move_group also crashed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351294/***-stack-smashing-detected-***:-/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group-terminated/) by [Jiawenxing](https://answers.ros.org/users/53229/jiawenxing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2020-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, I figure out this issue. The reason that I got this problem is that I installed the [libccd](http://wiki.ros.org/libccd) alone, it conflict with the internal library.
So i just uninstall the library.

---

Originally posted by [Jiawenxing](https://answers.ros.org/users/53229/jiawenxing/) with karma: 86 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2